# Complete list of processors that support SSE2?

Tags: cpu, specifications

I basically only find this online: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPU_support

But it seems quite incomplete (i.e. where's Intel Core)?

Is there a list of processors that support SSE2? Or how much its used/supported right now?

Comment: on this forum, you'll find a list (better as in wiki) https://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/14529-complete-list-of-intel-and-amd-sse2-and-sse3-processors/

Comment: A list like this would contain hundreds of processors.  Questions seeking "lists" are out of scope here at Superuser, I am not aware of any Stack Exchange community, where a question like this would be within scope.

Comment: why do you need to know that? All x86-64 CPUs support SSE2. And SSE2 support will never disappear in the future due to backward compatibility, unless Intel decided to change to a different architecture

Comment: @phuclv so only Intel and amd processor? And what about x86?

Comment: no, VIA also produced x86-64 CPUs, so obviously they must support SSE2. So did Transmeta. All CPUs after the first generation with SSE2 support must also have SSE2 support, like Intel Netburst onward except a few exceptions, mainly old embedded CPUs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPU_support but the main thing is that there's no need to know the list of all SSE2-enabled CPUs. You need to state why you want that

Comment: however if a CPU supports a later instruction set like SSE3 or AVX then it must supports all the previous ones like SSE2 and MMX

Comment: @phuclv because I'm compiling software that use some SSE2 intrinsics. And I need to understand which is the target available to my software. That's all. If I run it with ARM, it won't works...

Comment: you need to [check whether the CPU supports SSE2 or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403660/995714) instead of comparing the CPU with a known list. You can't know thousands of the CPUs out there and even more in the future that supports SSE2. And how is ARM relevant here? x86 binaries can't run on ARM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is literally the first 3 sentences at the point you linked in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPU_support):

> SSE2 is an extension of the IA-32 architecture, based on the x86 instruction set. Therefore, only x86 processors can include SSE2. The AMD64 architecture supports the IA-32 as a compatibility mode and includes the SSE2 in its specification

This means virtually every modern Intel and AMD CPU supports SSE2.